# Angular <img> conditional

Tags: angular, image, conditional-statements, src

I new to angular so please be comprehensive.

I have this HTML code :

```
    <div><img src="assets/images/red_no.png"/></div>
```

I want to choose the src depending on a variable which is true or false.
I've tried ng-src but can't make it work.
Also *ngIf but I can't seem to handle the templates right.

Thank you for your responses

Comment: You should show us what exactly you tried with `ng-src` and `ng-if`

Comment: Choose or change `src`?

Comment: Which version of Angular you are using? `ng-src` is for AngularJS and `*ngIf` is used in Angular. AngularJS and Angular are different frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition into your attribute something like this

```
<div><img [attr.src]="[true? 'assets/images/red_no.png' : '']"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your html:

```
<img [src]="this.showImage()">
```

in your .ts:

```
showImage(){
return statement ? 'assets/images/red_no' : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ternary operator` as like below:

```
<img [src]="variable? 'assets/images/red_no.png' : 'assets/images/another.png'" />
```